# $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in $L^q$ then $|x_n|^q\rightharpoonup |x|^q$ in some $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Consider $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a uniform bounded sequence in $L^1\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Then along a subsequence $x_{n_k}\rightharpoonup x$ in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for any $1<q<\infty$ and $x\in L^1\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. In the linear continuous case, say $T\in (L^q(\mathbb{R}^3))^{*}$ it follows $T(x_n)\rightharpoonup T(x)$, see for instance https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2796137. I was wondering if this is also true if $T$ isn't linear anymore for instance if $T(x)=|x|^p$, so is it true that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |x_n|^p \varphi dx \rightharpoonup \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |x|^p \varphi dx,$$
if $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in every $L^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for $1< q <\infty$.
We can decompose the integral as follows
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |x_n|^p \varphi ~dx =\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n x_n^{p-1} \varphi ~dx - \int_{\{x_n <0 \}} x_n x_n^{p-1} \varphi ~dx$$
for any $\varphi \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. We either have
$$ \int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n \|x_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{p-1} \varphi ~dx
\geq\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n x_n^{p-1} \varphi ~dx
\geq -\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n \|x_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{p-1} \varphi ~dx$$

or

$$ -\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n \|x_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{p-1} \varphi ~dx
\geq\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n x_n^{p-1} \varphi ~dx
\geq \int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n \|x_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{p-1} \varphi ~dx.$$

W.l.o.g. we are in the first case. Then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} C x_n \varphi dx\geq\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} C x_n  \varphi ~dx
\geq\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} x_n x_n^{p-1} \varphi ~dx
\geq -\int_{\{x_n\geq 0 \}} Cx_n  \varphi ~dx\geq -\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} C x_n \varphi dx$$

where $C=\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\|x_n\|_{L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)}^{p-1}$.
I just noticed that this is not helping at all... Is the statement even true? I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: The statement is not true.

Comment: Take the example in the answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4400109/weak-convergence-in-w-01-p-omega-implies-weak-convergence-in-l2-omega/4400151#4400151

Comment: This question has been asked many times already, could not find a more fitting answer.

Comment: If you construct the sequence in this way, it is not even in any $L^p(\mathbb{R})$. I don't think that this changes anything but just to be sure, is this also false if $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded in $L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Note, the functions in those answer are supported on the unit interval only, hence the are bounded in every $L^p(\mathbb R)$. The claim is false almost everytime, weak convergence in $L^p$ and nonlinear mappings do not go well with each other.